# Unable to focus input when hash is set

Tags: javascript, html, forms, focus

I've never noticed this before, but it seems it's not possible to focus an input field on load if a hash pointing to an existing element is set.

Why is this?

Look at this very basic example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Focus test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bar">
            <input name="foo">
        </div>
        <script>
            console.log(document.activeElement);
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
            console.log(document.activeElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you load up that page in Chrome the input will be focused. If you set the hash to #bar and reload the page the input will *not* be focused. If you set the hash to #non-existing-element the input once again will be focused.

`activeElement` says `body` and later `input` regardless of whether a hash is set or not strangely enough.

Comment: What is the question ? What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: Why is it not possible to focus an input field when a hash is set is the question. Expected behaviour is that the input gets focus.

Comment: How would browser determine what to prefer ? What about `hash` in the URL ? I am unable to provide convincing reference but this is how it should behave.. Setting `focus` after `setTimeout` will help!

Comment: Ok so you're saying when both a hash is set, and at the same time I focus another element, the browser won't know which element should really have focus? I'm confused as to why `document.activeElement` _never_ points to the element set in the hash though. And I wasn't aware that setting a hash is the same as focusing an element. Giving the `input` and id and pointing the hash to that _does not_ focus it, so I don't see how they're the same thing.

Comment: @Rayon using `setTimeout` works though! :) So thanks a lot. Post it in an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 scenarios considering this use case:

> 1. Page is `loaded`/`refreshed` when there is no hash in the URL

*In this case, `Element.focus()` works fine.*

> 2. Hash in the URL is `appended` but page is not `reloaded`/`refreshed`

*In this case, [**`HashChangeEvent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HashChangeEvent) could be used to set the `focus` over element.*

> 3. Page is `loaded`/`refreshed` when there **is** hash in the URL

*In this case, `Element.focus()` works fine **if** invoked in the `callback` of `setTimeout`. Even a `setTimeout(callback,0)` will work!*

> 4. Page is `loaded`/`refreshed` when there *is* hash in the URL but `target` does not exist in the Page

*In this case, `Element.focus()` works fine*

**Final thought:**

To have a `focus` ever element in *any* scenario, Use `setTimeout` in the `window.onload` callback with the `delay` of *0*

```
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
    console.log(document.activeElement);
  }, 0);
};
```